# threejs - add padding around a tubeGeometry

Tags: three.js

I have a thin tube which is clickable but it's very hard to click it. I would like to add an invisible padding around the tube to make it easier to click. Below is the code:

```
<mesh onClick={this.onClick}>
  <tubeGeometry
    path={curve}
    radius={0.3}
    segments={8}
    radiusSegments={8}
  />
  <materialResource resourceId={"connectionMaterial" + layer} />
</mesh>
```

Is there a way to add a padding to the mesh?

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to do this is to create a second tube around the first at the desired clickable size. When creating the material for your tube simply provide the following arguments so that it will be invisible but clickable.

```
let mat = new MeshBasicMaterial({ 
color: #ffffff,
side: DoubleSide,
alphaTest: 0,
lights: false });
```

Additionally to tie your tubes together cleanly you can do one of two things:

- Create a single `Group` and `.add()` both tubes to the group.
- `.add()` your clickable tube to your visible tube.

I hope that helps!

edit:

You can add one `Object3d` as the child of another by using `.add()`. This looks like:

```
import { Group } from 'three'; // es6 

let myTube; // Your visible tube
let myClickableTube; // Your larger clickable tube

let group = new Group(); // This will hold both tubes
group.add(myTube);
group.add(myClickableTube);
```

or

```
let myTube; // Your visible tube
let myClickableTube; // Your larger clickable tube

myTube.add(myClickableTube);
```

Comment: Just a note: This is setting the **material**'s visibility to `false`, which is different from setting the **object**'s visibility to `false`. `Raycaster.intersectObject`/`Raycaster.intersectObjects` will skip invisible _objects_.

Comment: ah, shoot. Good catch, I copied this from one of my projects where we initially don't allow raycasting against the control object.

edit: fixed answer

Comment: Id do visible on the material instead of the alphatest

Comment: Thank you, would you mind adding a code example showing how to `.add()`, thanks

Comment: @pailhead Agreed. It's being used incorrectly anyway. [`Material.alphaTest` docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/Material.alphaTest)

Comment: "Sets the alpha value to be used when running an alpha test. The material will not be renderered if the opacity is lower than this value. Default is 0." Seems like it's being used correctly to me.